# Which IEnumerable To a List way is better?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, collections, ienumerable

I am wondering about the following fact. I have a data repository that returns all my data of `IEnumerable<Customer>`.

In my business logic sometimes I need lists so I can add stuff for example.

When I retrieve the `IEnumerable<Customer>` I have 2 options to get a list from it.

Either using the Linq extension method `.ToList()` or cast it (I think its not a conversion) like this `(List<Customer>)IEnumerable<Customer>`.

Must mention that I don't use the list for iterations so I don't need a new copy of my enumeration each time. In this case is it true that in my simple case I must use the cast method instead of `.ToList` (which creates a new copy) ?

```
// use simple cast?
List<Customer> customers = (List<Customers>)DataSource.GetCustomers(); 

// or if i use this i get a bit of performance loss?
List<Customer> customers = DataSource.GetCustomers().ToList();
```

Comment: When you say data repository do you mean your ORM data access class?

Comment: yes it's entity framework but its about the collection itself regardless from where it comes

Comment: Just didn't know if it was returning an IQueryable()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The whole point of your repository returning an IEnumerable is that it isn't guaranteed to actually be a list. (It may be now, but the use of IEnumerable allows the implementation to be changed later).

Either go with the .ToList() method, or make the repository return a List or IList instead.

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific about the part where "IEnumerable allows the implementation to be changed later"?

Comment: I mean even if the data acces layer.part of the app changes is it not a good practice to return a collection in a more "primitive" way like an IEnumerable? And if the data acces layer will always return only these type why make a new list each time?

Comment: @Freeman: If the implementation today in reality returns a list, what is the reason to mark the method as returning an IEnumerable? The reason is that returning an IEnumerable allows the programmer to later change it to return an array or any other type of collection. The modified code would (should) fit in anywhere the original code was used. (So now, if you try to cast it to a List, your code will no longer work.)

Comment: @Freeman: If "good practice" dictates that your return IEnumerable, then its also "good practice" to not expect the result to actually be a List (which you do when casting it to a List). If it was meant to be treated as a List or IList, it should also be returned as such.

Answer (score 5):

I'd go with the `ToList()`, since the method returns an `IEnumerable<Customer>` and you cannot be sure of the inner implementation.

Maybe now `GetCustomers()` returns a `List<>` masked by an `IEnumerable<>`, but what if in the future the inner implementation changes ?

**EDIT :**

`List<Customer>` implements the interface `IEnumerable<Customer>`, as well as an array like `Customer[]` or a `LinkedList<Customer>`. Hence, when you receive an object of type `IEnumerable<WhateverClass>` you cannot be sure it is a `List<Customer>` and, of course, the cast works only if the type you're casting to is the same behind the interface, otherwise you will receive an exception.

Using `ToList()`, as you correctly said, you create a new object containing the elements of the `IEnumerable<>`, but at least you can safely iterate/modify that object without any exception.

The methods returns `IEnumerable<T>` because in this way it is not bound to any specific collection implementation, and in the future it can switch for example from list to array or whatever without changing the method signature...

Comment: must i understand that not any IEnumerable<Something> can be cast to a List<Something> ?

Comment: @Freeman: Anything can _implement_ `IEnumerable<Something>` but not be a list.  For example: `public class MySomethings : IEnumerable<Something>`  If you don't know it's actually list, the cast will fail.  EDIT: But you can easily _create_ a new List from the IEnumerable, either via Linq with `ToList` or simply as `new List<Something>(myEnumerable)`

Comment: I am sure its always an IEnumerable, and usually when people want to return a simple collection so later on, they can play with it as they wish.

Comment: @digEmAll just got what you have been saying. For example i just got an exception because i was trying to sort an IEnumerable<Customer> after destroying the data context. The point is that this IEnumerable<Customer> was at its base type an ObjectQuery that could only have been sorted after the collection was enumerated(in my case query the db), this way i realized that if i had a cast it would have thrown me a runtime error because ObjectContext != List<Customer>

Comment: @Freeman: exactly :) Use `ToList()` then you can freely manipulate it in memory.

Answer (score 2):

It depends. If the size is small I'd go with the .ToList(), but you have to understand that this will do a copy of the list.

If it's big or you're doing it a lot (and it creates performance penalty) you can check if the returned object from .GetCustomers() is a list
if yes - cast, else create a copy with .ToList().

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using .ToList(). It will perform worse but if you cast you are using information about the implementation details of the API and you are making unwarranted assumptions. Tomorrow someone will change the IEnumerable to something that is not a list and your code will start throwing exceptions.

Comment: It's not violating the contract, it's making unwarranted assumptions.

Answer (score 1):

You can go with the cast by using a condition, to safeguard against future implementation changes. Something like

```
List<Customer> customers = null;
try
{
     customers = (List<Customers>)DataSource.GetCustomers();
}
catch
{
    customers = DataSource.GetCustomers().ToList();
}
```

This way, you can avoid copying the list, as long as the IEnumerable is a list, but your code will keep working if, for some reason, in the future the inner implementation changes.